# Java Utility Singleton With Matching Static Interface

Tags: java, java-8, singleton, static-methods

I would like to make a set of utility classes that implement an interface.  In order to do this, I will be using the singleton pattern.  However, it would also be nice to be able to use those utility classes via static method calls.  For example:

```
public interface IValidator<T> {
    boolean isValid(T value);
}

public class StringValidator implements IValidator<String> {
    public static final StringValidator instance = new StringValidator();

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above provides a singleton which enables me to call the utility methods using an interface, as follows:

```
// Use case #1
IValidator<String> validator1 = StringValidator.instance;
validator1.isValid("");

// Use case #2
StringValidator.instance.isValid("");
```

However, I would also like to be able to use `StringValidator` in the following, more succinct way:

```
// Use case #3: How can I also allow this syntax?
StringValidator.isValid("");
```

Is there a way in Java to make all three of the above syntaxes work without renaming the method?  The only idea I had was to add a varargs parameter to the static definition, as follows:

```
public class StringValidator implements IValidator<String> {
    public static final StringValidator instance = new StringValidator();

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String value) {
        return StringValidator.isValid(value);
    }

    public static boolean isValid(final String value, final Object... ignored) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, that fails with the message "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method isValid(String) from the type StringValidator".  Again, is there some way to make the compiler allow all three of my use-case syntaxes?  Thanks.

Comment: I would not expect so. Generally speaking, the way to deal with this would be to static-import the instance from the class...

Comment: What is wrong with `StringValidator.instance.isValid("");`?

Answer (score 3):

If the interface is a functional interface you could drop the singleton

```
public class StringValidator {
    public static boolean isValid(final String value) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

and whenever you need a instance of `Validator<String>` use a method handle to the static method:

```
IValidator<String> validator1 = StringValidator::isValid;
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a way.  Change the code to the following:

```
public interface IValidator<T> {
    boolean isValid(T value, Object... ignored);
}

public class StringValidator implements IValidator<String> {
    public static final StringValidator instance = new StringValidator();

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String value, final Object... ignored) {
        return isValid(value);
    }

    public static boolean isValid(final String value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then all three of the use cases compile.  Java will generate a warning for use case #2, but that doesn't bother me as I think the only sane use of the implementing class are cases #1 and #3.

Comment: That doesn't look like a nice way to do it: introducing `ignored` variables is a code-smell. And ignoring compiler warnings is never a good idea.

Comment: I find the entirety of the Java language to be a code smell.  Type erasure, in particular, produces the foulest of odors.

Comment: @Tunaki I ended up just scrapping use case #3 (e.g., just accepting that I have to type ".instance" between the class and method name), even though my solution does answer the original question.  I agree that it is not a good solution, and advise any future visitors to avoid using this technique.